# AngularJS - How to access an array property inside an object with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array

I am trying to learn AngularJS and am having trouble with ng-repeat an possibly my data structure.

Here is the situation:

I have table 1, where users input information such as the column title, data type, and whether its editable. Then when a user adds a row, I store the data in a column object, which is then pushed into a columns array

```
var column = {
    checked: $scope.checked,
    title: $scope.title,
    type: $scope.type,
    editable: $scope.editable,
    data: []
};
$scope.columns.push(column);
```

Then based on that table, I have another table created. Each column title goes off of the titles entered in Table 1, and the user can add rows to table 2. If anything is changed on Table 1, then Table 2 needs to be updated appropriately.

However this is where I am having trouble. I am trying to store the data that would be entered in Table 2 in the column object in an empty data array. So when a new row gets added to Table 2, an 'empty cell' will get pushed into each column data array. When I go to display each 'cell' with ng-repeat, I don't know how to access the array inside the column object, inside the columns array.

When I try and add rows, and create a space to store the data for each table-cell:

```
<tr ng-repeat="column in columns">
<td> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="getIndex($index, rows)"></input></td>
<td ng-repeat="value in column.data track by $index"> {{value}} </td>
</tr>
```

But it has the opposite effect that I want. I want the first ng-repeat to be based on **value in column.data** and the second one to be based on **column in columns**. Perhaps my data is structured poorly, but I couldn't think of another way to store the data, while table 2 updates whenever a change is made in table 1.

I found that you can do ng-repeat=(key, value) in data, but I don't think that can apply to this situation? Any help at all would be much appreciated, I have been stuck on this for a week.

If I need to clarify my question more, let me know!

Edit: [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyrtle/6o17gnpd/3/). I should have just done this first. Shortened my question a lot

Comment: Please show more of your controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have control similar to what you are doing in our project.Here is what we do:

there is an object that represents both structure and data of the table:

```
     var tableDescriptor = {
        definition: [{title: 'col 1', type: 'String'}, 
             {title:'col 2', type: 'Number'}],

        data: [
           [ {value: 'a stirng'}, {value: 1} ],
           [ {value: 'b stirng'}, {value: 2} ],
        ]
     }
```

I.e. array of column objects and array of rows, which are arrays of cells

Now, we don't do edit of definition and data at the same time, but basically what you want to do is to have 3 directives:

- table wrapper - owns data and definition, listens to events

and template like

```
  <div>
      <definition-editor definition='descr.definition'></definition-editor>
      <data-editor data='descr.data' definition='descr.definition'></data-editor>
  </div>
```

- definition editor - allow to change definition
- data editor - allow to change data

Data editor just going to be simple

```
 <tr>
     <th ng-repeat='column in definition'> {{ column.title }}</th>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat='row in data track by $index'>
     <td>{{ $index }}</td>
     <td ng-repeat='cell in row track by $index'>
         <field data='cell' ></field>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

While definition editor going to do almost exactly what you are doing, and in addition to changing columns, it is going to emit events:

- add column   `$scope.$emit('table-add-column', i)`
- delete column `$scope.$emit('table-delete-column', i)`

You then going to listen to those events in your parrent directive and update body correspondingly, ie

```
$scope.$on('table-add-column', function(ev, i) {
   _.forEach($scope.descriptor.data, function(row) {
       row.splice(i, 0, { value: ''})
   })
})

$scope.$on('table-delete-column', function(ev, i) {
   _.forEach($scope.descriptor.data, function(row) {
       row.splice(i, 1)
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I thought about storing the data in another array, but never thought about grouping them in an overall object! I am a bit new to Angular, so what is the benefit of using _.forEach instead of angular.forEach? Also does your second table update to any change made in the first table?

Comment: @Tyrtle Those $emit and $on are exactly for that. $emit tells that there is a change to first table and $on updates second one. You can use angular.forEach just fine. They are doing the same thing in a nutshell.